# github: PGP key usage flags do not allow signing

Tags: git, github, gnupg, pgp

I've used my OpenPGP key to sign a git commit, but it shows up as "Unverified" on github: https://github.com/cweiske/jsonmapper/commits/master

> The usage flags for the key that signed this don't allow signing.
>
> GPG key ID: 14C85A0824EAF823

The [github gpg signature docs](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/) say nothing about that error.

So my questions:

1. How do I read those flags?
2. How can I change my key to allow code signing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at your signing capabilities [by either looking at the output of `--edit-key` or GnuPG's colon-separated output](https://superuser.com/q/833875/102155).

Looking at your key, I see that you have a bunch of expired subkeys (some with signing capability), and a primary key that has signing and certification capabilities set. The primary key's expiry period was extended twice (also consider reading ["Does OpenPGP key expiration add to security?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/14718/19837) on this subject).

I see two possible issues here:

- GitHub does not have the newest copy of your public key yet. Because of this, the key that issued the signature is not considered as a signing key as it seems expired to GitHub. Still, the error message is a bad one, and GitHub should tell you about an expired key instead. Uploading a newer copy of the key should resolve the issue.
- There is a bug in the GitHub software that makes it ignore the primary key when signing subkeys exist (no matter whether they're expired or not).

Comment: I've uploaded the latest version, but it still was considered invalid. I've contacted github support.

Comment: I got a response from github's support: They know about the problem but do not know when they will fix it :/

Comment: I guess adding a new signing subkey will resolve the issue, and is good practise anyway.